# Boto3 Client 'Scheduler'

Tags: boto3, scheduler, aws-event-bridge

can anyone help me on this? I want to create a AWS EventBridge Scheduler using Boto3 but I'm encountering this error `botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'scheduler'` what am I missing?

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('scheduler') 
response = client.create_schedule(Name='test',FlexibleTimeWindow=. {'Mode':'OFF'},ScheduleExpression='rate(5 minutes)',) 
return response
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to **upgrade** your boto3. `sheduler` is a new aws offering, thus newest `boto3` is required.